# Facebook Marketing API adaccounts

Tags: php, facebook

I'm having some trouble with the Facebook Marketing API. I need to read all the active campaings the current user has, in all of his ad accounts. So, the first step is to read all the ad accounts.

First, I tried what the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/sdks) says:

```
// Add to header of your file
use FacebookAds\Object\AdUser;

// Add after Api::init()
$me = new AdUser('me');
$my_adaccount = $me->getAdAccounts()->current();
```

But the AdUser.php file doesn't exists in the SDK.

So, I tried doing a request to the endpoint /me/adaccounts

```
$fb = new Facebook([
    'app_id'     => AppId,
    'app_secret' => AppSecret,
]);

$response = $fb->get('/me/adaccounts', Token);
```

This throws an error saying I'm using a deprecated version of the Marketing API (but I'm using the 3.2!!). I also tried

```
$response = $fb->get('me?fields=adaccounts', Token);
```

And got the same error. Can anyone help me find another way??

PS: English is not my first language, sorry about that...

Comment: Could it be that they changed something, and you have to use AdAccountUser now instead? (That at least has a method getAdAccounts.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Check this solution!

```
    // Add after Api::init()

    $user = new \FacebookAds\Object\User();
    $user->setId($userID);
    $user->setApi($api);

    $accounts = $user->getAdAccounts(array(\FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdFields::NAME));
    foreach ($accounts as $acc) {
      echo $acc->name;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using php SDK**

```
try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->get(
    '/<USER_ID>/adaccounts',
    '{access-token}'
  );
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check campaigns using insights api. Type following line in explorer and see the magic

me/campaigns?fields=id,name,status,effective_status

This will give you list of 25 campaigns and you can read their status & effective status.
You can use php sdk syntax call above api url and read response.